# Using only one specific document as source in llm - chainlit

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

Hi I'm trying to implement this code from one of the chainlit documentation on using llm to chat with your documents. What I want is to use chainlit to talk to specific document withing the docsearch using the source. Basically, I will send an input text and tell the AI to use a specific source to generate the response.

Please can any one help on this?

```
import chainlit as cl
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import (
    ConversationalRetrievalChain,
)
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory, ChatMessageHistory

async def sample_function(_docs, user_input):
    
  embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2", model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
  docsearch = Chroma(
            collection_name="full_documents",
            embedding_function=embeddings )

  docsearch.add_documents(_docs)

  message_history = ChatMessageHistory()

  memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    memory_key="chat_history",
    output_key="answer",
    chat_memory=message_history,
    return_messages=True,
)

  # Create a chain that uses the Chroma vector store as a retriever
  chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
      ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4-1106-preview", temperature=0, streaming=True),
      chain_type="stuff",
      retriever=docsearch.as_retriever() if docsearch else None,
      memory=memory,
      return_source_documents=True,
  )
  
  cb = cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler()

  res = await chain.acall(user_input, callbacks=[cb])
  answer = res["answer"]

  # result = start_chat_script(user_input, answer, doument_from_storage[0].page_content)

  message_history.add_user_message(user_input)
  message_history.add_ai_message(answer)
  # assistant_responses.append(answer)
  source_documents = res["source_documents"]
  text_elements = []  # type: List[cl.Text]
  unique_sources = set()  # Set to store unique source names

  if source_documents:
      for source_doc in source_documents:
          source_name = source_doc.metadata["source"]
          if source_name not in unique_sources:
              # Create the text element referenced in the message
              text_elements.append(
                  cl.Text(content=source_doc.page_content, name=source_name)
              )
              unique_sources.add(source_name)

      source_names = [text_el.name for text_el in text_elements]

      if source_names:
          answer += "\n\nSources:"
          for source_idx, source_name in enumerate(source_names[:2], start=1):
              answer += f"\n{source_idx}. {source_name}"
      else:
          answer += "\nNo sources found"

  return answer, text_elements
```